# Non-persistant sharepoint column

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Is it possible to create a sharepoint list with a column that is just a placeholder to be filled in using javascript? I'd like to create a column and update its value when the page is loaded based on our internal business logic. There is no need to save the results along with the field (the results would change daily based on market data).

EDIT:
This is my code:

```
function UpdateItem(id, calcVal) {
   var uctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = uctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   this.oListItem = list.getItemById(id);
   oListItem.set_item('NonPersistantColumn', calcVal);
   oListItem.update();
   uctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUpdateSucceeded),     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUpdateFailed));
}
```

The execute query is *not* what I want I think as it updates the back-end value of the column. Is there a way I can re-render the front end? If I comment out the executeQueryAsync call, the front end remains unchanged.

Comment: I don't see anything preventing it, the trick would just be getting your javascript right. It might make it easier to set the default column value to something specific, which you then find via your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding script in the page that will update the value of the column. Use client object model to update the column.